# Passing a method in an annotation

Tags: java

I created an annotation like below

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TestData
{
String[] values();

}
```

I use it in my class like below

```
@TestData({"test1","test2","test3"})

public void testMethod(String data) {
   //Some code here
}
```

What I'd like to do is.. For the TestData annotation I'd like to dynamically generate a few values and pass it on. For Eg:

Let's say I have a method called getData();

```
public string[] getData() {
   //Code to return an array
   return array[];
}
```

Now I want to be able to pass the values of getData() method to my @TestData annotation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible, the values that are on the annotation have to be known at compile time, so you cannot use the result of a method, because that won't be known until you run the program.

This is explained in [JLS 9.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) (the description of the ElementValue, V). This paragraph says:

- if the type is primitive or `String` it must be a constant expression (i.e. a compile-time constant)
- if the type is `Class` it must be a class literal
- if the type is an enum it must be an enum constant
- if the type is an array then the above rules are applicable to the array elements

The return value of a method is not a compile-time constant.